# Fat tails equal higher probability of non-extreme values according to Nassim Taleb?

Tags: distributions, extreme-value, kurtosis

I just came across the following passage written by Nassim Taleb [Link](https://fooledbyrandomness.com/DarwinCollege.pdf):

*The fattest tail distribution has just one very large extreme deviation, rather than many departures form the norm. [...] if we take a distribution like the Gaussian and start fattening it, then the number of departures away from one standard deviation drops. The probability of an event staying within one standard deviation of the mean is 68 per cent. As we the tails fatten, to mimic what happens in financial markets for example, the probability of an event staying within one standard deviation of the mean rises tobetween 75 and 95 per cent.*

So as far as I understand he states that the fatter the tails, the higher the probability of an observation falling into the window of 1 SD away from the mean. I have read definitions elsewhere that basically state that fat tails imply more extreme observations (i.e. a higher probability of extreme observations). Intuitively I feel that this contradicts what Mr. Taleb is saying and hence, I am having issues to relate what Mr. Taleb is saying with the aforementioned definition.

Could someone shed light on the point Mr. Taleb is trying to make? Maybe, my confusion stems from a misconception of what a fat tail is in the first place. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There are several threads here on this pugnacious pundit. Although this doesn't answer your question, which is why it's a comment, I have long since concluded that sometimes he makes a standard point clearly and even entertainingly, but when it's not clear what he's  saying it's a waste of time to try to puzzle it out.

Comment: pugnacious ? eager or quick to argue, quarrel, or fight.
"his public statements became increasingly pugnacious"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
"As ... the tails fatten ... the probability of an event staying within one 
standard deviation of the mean rises to between 75 and 95 per cent"
```

may be true within narrow families of probability distributions, but it is false in general.  Here is a counterexample, edited from here, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2510884/472987 , where the probability within a standard deviation stays constant (0.5) as the tails fatten.

Let $X = \mu + \sigma Z$, where $Z$ has the discrete distribution

$Z = -0.5$,   with probability (wp) $.25$

$= +0.5$,   wp $.25$

$= -1.2$,   wp $.25 - \theta/2$

$= +1.2$,   wp $.25 - \theta/2$

$= -\sqrt{0.155/\theta + 1.44}$,  wp $\theta/2$

$= +\sqrt{0.155/\theta + 1.44}$,  wp $\theta/2$.

The family of distributions of $X$ is indexed by three parameters: $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $\theta$, with ranges $(-\infty, +\infty)$, $(0, +\infty)$ and $(0,.5)$.

In this family, $E(X) = \mu$, $Var(X) = \sigma^2$, and the kurtosis of $X$ is as follows:

kurtosis $= E(Z^4) = .5^4 * .5 + 1.2^4 * (.5 - \theta) + (0.155/\theta + 1.44)^2 * \theta$.

Within this family,

(i) kurtosis tends to $\infty$ as $\theta \rightarrow 0$.

(ii) the distribution within the "shoulders" (i.e., within the $\mu \pm \sigma$ range) is constant for all values of kurtosis; it is simply the two points $\mu \pm \sigma/2$, wp $0.25$ each. This provides a counterexample to one interpretation of kurtosis, which states that larger kurtosis implies movement of mass away from the shoulders, simultaneously into the range between the shoulders and into the tails.

(iii) the "peak" of the distribution is also constant for all value of kurtosis; again, it is simply the two points $\mu \pm \sigma/2$, wp $0.25$ each. This provides a counterexample to the often given but obviously incorrect interpretation that larger kurtosis implies a more "peaked" distribution.

(iv) In this family, the central portion of the distribution actually becomes flatter as kurtosis increases, since the probabilities on  $\mu \pm 1.2\sigma$ and $\mu \pm 0.5\sigma$ converge to the same value, $0.25$, as the kurtosis increases. This provides a counterexample to the often-stated interpretation that higher kurtosis corresponds to "peakedness" and lower kurtosis corresponds to "flatness." Within this given family of distributions, higher kurtosis actually corresponds to a flatter peak.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I am actually a bit stunned by how he makes these statements. He apparently ridicules people not understanding statistics and then creates a false sense of "oh now I really got it" in some cases - at least it appears to me like this.

Comment: Yeah, hyperbole.  I wrote a review of his Black Swan book that detailed many other criticisms, but also offered credit where credit is due.  He has some really good points, IMO, and maybe the hyperbole (and associated incorrect statements) is a deliberate device to get people to pay attention.  https://www.academia.edu/24076106/The_Black_Swan_Praise_and_Criticism

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at it.

Comment: In your counterexample, decreasing theta means taking probability mass from only the most extreme parts of the distribution and redistributing it between the intermediate parts and even more extreme areas. But Taleb's diagram implies that by "fattening the tails" he means not just any change which increases kurtosis, but specifically something like taking probability mass more evenly from the whole distribution and redistributing it to the extreme parts [and rescaling the distribution so the variance doesn't change].

Comment: Right, within narrow families of distributions his contention holds, but it does not hold more generally.

Comment: But he explicitly states that he is talking about "a distribution like the Gaussian". I agree with his claim that "fattening the tails" of such a distribution in the way that his graph depicts reduces the number of departures away from one standard deviation.

Comment: Like a lot of Taleb's statements, that is too vague ... Can you state it as a theorem?

Comment: Anyway, you can mix my distribution above with an *exact* normal($\mu,\sigma^2$) (not "like" a normal), with probability $\theta$ on the normal and $1-\theta $ on mine.  Then you still have a family with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, that is *exactly* normal for $\theta =1$. Then as $\theta \rightarrow 0$, it morphs to a distribution that has kurtosis tending to infinity, with all the properties that I mentioned in my post intact.  So it is not enough to start with a normal and move mass around to make Taleb's arguments stick.

Comment: I think Taleb means it as more of a rule of thumb than a theorem. And it is pretty widely applicable in real life, e.g. increasing the number of billionaires increases the number of people within 1 standard deviation of the mean wealth, increasing the probability of a financial crisis makes it likelier the change in a stock price will be within 1 standard deviation of the mean, and increasing the number of people with growth disorders increases the number of people who are within 1 standard deviation of the mean height. It's harder to come up with practical examples where it doesn't hold.

Comment: Sounds like a popular misconception of heavy tails.  Adding billionaires does not fatten the tails, it reduces them.  Heaviness of tails refers to both extremity and rareness. If you add more billionaires to an existing sample, you actually *reduce* the kurtosis.  As far as practical examples, you could just mimic my example, where the extremes become more extreme and simultaneously more rare. Consider a sequence of samples where the extreme is larger and larger, while the rest of the sample size increases but stays put in its location.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, but the wealth example can still be brought in scope by replacing "billionaires" with "people rich enough to actually increase the kurtosis".